# PHP $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] no longer giving users ipaddress as expected?

Tags: php

Before PHP 5.4 when running retrieving the users IPAddress using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` the result would be the users external IPV6 IPAddress.
EG: **60.123.456.168**

However since updating my server to PHP 5.4 the returned users IPAddress seems to be their internal IP:
EG: **192.168.1.34**

This becomes an issue if you want a specific office or 'router' to see a particular group of content or in our case debug code.
I tried using the other IP option `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` but this isn't available on all servers.

Is their another way to grab the users external ipaddress in PHP >= 5.4 or has this functionality been removed?

Comment: `print_r($_SERVER);`, is it in there?

Comment: Are you running the script on localhost?

Comment: P.s. Yes i searched for this in Stack Exchange and Google before asking :) No luck

Comment: Im running the script on a live server, Nope the external IP is not found in the $SERVER globals

Answer (score 1):

this even checks for proxy servers and still reveal correct user ip

```
<?php
function get_real_ip()
{

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"];
    }
    else
    {
        return $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

}
$IP_Address = get_real_ip();

echo $IP_Address
?>
```

Comment: he started no server variable contained the correct ip, so this wont help

Comment: Your Common Sense, rather than running your mouth about it not working, how about uploading the php to a server and finding out? I even tested while running a CyberGhost 5

Answer (score 1):

It is not PHP's fault. PHP doesn't detect anything but just reading environment variable.
You have some proxy probably, that is not properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Figured out this issue appears to be due to our Newb server setup.
As the server was in fact running from a localhost and networked through Windows (I wasn't aware it was till now).
This explains why the Local IPAddress was coming up.

False alarm :)

Thanks everyone for your help though!